# Explain different types of draw buffers

Tags: opengl, glsl

Why do we need all these buffers:

GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRONT_RIGHT,
       GL_BACK_LEFT, GL_BACK_RIGHT, GL_FRONT,  GL_BACK,  GL_LEFT,
       GL_RIGHT,  GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,  and  GL_AUXi,  where  i  is
       between  0  and  GL_AUX_BUFFERS.

GL_FRONT and GL_BACK make sense to me, but not others. Can someone give an example when we will be rendering to say GL_BACK_LEFT?

When I say GL_FRONT_ABD_BACK, does it render to all left and right of both front and back buffers (ie 4 buffers in total). What are the use-cases of rendering the same image to all 4 buffers?  Any examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LEFT/RIGHT distinction for the buffers is used for stereo display. For double buffered stereo, you would render the image for the left eye into the GL_BACK_LEFT buffer, the image for the right eye into the GL_BACK_RIGHT buffer, and then swap buffers.

In stereo mode, GL_BACK is used if you want to render the same thing to both GL_BACK_LEFT_ and GL_BACK_RIGHT. Which is quite rare.

You're correct about GL_FRONT_AND_BACK. Rendering to the front buffer is long obsolete, and was only useful in special cases anyway. One typical case was for drawing special cursors, like cross-hair cursors, using OpenGL, on top of an already displayed frame. Rendering to both front and back at the same time was even less useful. I can't think of a good use case right now.

AUX buffers are long deprecated as well. I believe they were intended for rendering effects where you needed additional color buffers. These days, you would use FBOs for the same purpose.

Comment: 1 follow up question. What is the difference between: rendering to back buffer and then swapping front & back buffers. vs  rendering to front buffer and then swapping front and back buffers. Will the latter show some artifacts?

Comment: @viktorzeid: Swapping in a back buffer that received no explicit drawing commands produces undefined results, i.e. anything may show up.

Comment: @viktorzeid As Reto said, there's literally no point in rendering directly to the front buffer. The front buffer is what the screen displays, while the back buffer is where you render to until the frame is complete.

Comment: @datenwolf, Thanks but i think I knew both those things. But my question is more like what if I deliberately render to front buffer first, and then swap. I am more interested in knowing what the user will see "before swap" if the GPU is slow.. will we see partially rendered geometry, or that much rendering as much was requested by 1 single draw call..

Comment: @viktorzeid: After the buffer swap the contents are undefined. And before the swap you might be able to glimpse at the drawing while it is created; or not, if the graphics system is using composition and needs a glFinish or buffer swap.

Comment: `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` actually has its uses. You can clear ***all*** of the buffers in your swap-chain in a single API call using it. That is to say, front/back as well as each of their left/right buffers (if they have them). Remember that this part of the API does not let you explicitly specify individual buffers like `glDrawBuffers (...)`, which was introduced with FBOs, does. So to do things like clear multiple buffers at once you had to use special wildcard tokens like `GL_FRONT` (which actually means front left AND front right, but this distinction only matters if you actually have stereo).

Answer (score 1):

The FRONT and BACK distinction refers to double buffering--usually a program draws to the back buffer and then swaps it to the front such that a complete frame is always presented to the user.

The LEFT and RIGHT distinction is for stereo rendering (where a slightly different viewpoint is used to render images for the left and right eyes).

Of course, most stereo rendering hardware would also support double buffering, leading to the combinations GL_FRONT/BACK_LEFT/RIGHT.

What buffers are actually available depends on the context you have requested and (of course) the capabilities of the underlying system.  GL_FRONT is likely to have the same defined value as one or the other of GL_FRONT_LEFT and GL_FRONT_RIGHT, and likewise for GL_BACK, though there's no guarantee.

The GL_AUXi buffers are implementation specific.  I suspect they're usually used for overlay planes when available.